# Reading Lines Between "Name" Lines into a Dictionary Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a file which has the format of  a line which is the name is then followed by an undefined amount of data lines and then the next name followed by the next amount of data lines. This repeats for about 300 names.

I am trying to save the name and the data into a dictionary as I am hoping to manipulate the data afterwards.

I am unable to find examples of how to separate the lines of a file into a dictionary with the key of the protein name listed above in the text.

I have been able to create an empty dictionary with keys of the protein names but cannot figure out or find out online how to store the lines in between each regular expression in the dictionary.

Each name line starts with `>`

An example of this is below.

```
>Position   Peptide Score   Cutoff    
>AAR88322    
1   *********M|DAMK 0.253   0    
2   ********MD|AMKR 0.601   0
3   *******MDA|MKRG 0.353   0
4   ******MDAM|KRGL 0.204   0
5   *****MDAMK|RGLC 0.326   0
6   ****MDAMKR|GLCC 0.125   0
>AAR88321
1   *********M|DAMK 0.253   0
2   ********MD|AMKR 0.601   0
3   *******MDA|MKRG 0.353   0
4   ******MDAM|KRGL 0.204   0
5   *****MDAMK|RGLC 0.326   0
```

I have been able to create empty dictionaries with this code

```
if len(parts) < 2:
    prot_number = parts[0]
    dict[prot_number[1:]]= []
```

Any help or suggestion on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm that will do that:

1. Open the file and iterate over it
2. Search for your name lines
3. If we find a name line, store it as a new dictionary key
4. If not, store the current line as part of a list that corresponds to the most recent name encountered

BTW, I'm ignoring how you're creating the dictionary in your example because whatever you're trying to do doesn't really make sense to me.

Example:

```
name_dict = {} # create empty dictionary

with open (file_name, 'r') as fi: # open file

    for line in fi:               # iterate over the lines

        if line.startswith('>'):  # check for name line marker
            current_name = line.lstrip('>') # store name without angle bracket
            name_dict[current_name] = [] # create dictionary entry with empty list

        else:
            name_dict[current_name].append(line) # not a name line, add to current name's list of lines
```

This will produce a dictionary whose keys are the names, and each name's value is a list of the lines that were found in its section. It will be up to you to figure out how you want to process the data, but you can do a lot of preprocessing as you store the non-name lines in the dictionary to make future processing more simple. For example, you can split the lines and strip off all of those asterisks before storing the line.

Comment: Thank You very much. I have been able to use this and achieve what I wanted.